# Find Standard Deviation given Population and Proportion Info

Tags: statistics

I know the answer is D but how?

There is a 30% chance of missing a flight due to long lines at security. If there are 120 people waiting in the security line to make their flight, what is the mean and standard deviation for the number of people who will miss their flight?: *

A) 3.6, 25.2
B) 3.6, 5.02
C) 36. 25.2
D) 36, 5.02

Comment: *Correction* find mean and standard deviation

Comment: Most easily solved using the normal approximation to a binomial distribution.  You can read about that, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

The number of people who miss their flight has binomial$(n=120,p=.3)$ distribution, so the mean is $np$ and the variance is $np(1-p)$ and the SD is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$. These work out to: mean = $120\cdot0.3=36$, SD = $\sqrt{120\cdot0.3\cdot 0.7}=\sqrt{25.20}=5.02$.